# Isn't it possible to modify a DevOps Center pipeline after the project has been running?

Tags: devopscenter

I have defined a project for our production instance so that we could at least build things in a couple of sandboxes before pushing to production (so just two stages: development and production).

Now that we finally have finished previous work and are able to refresh our partial and full copy sandboxes, I would like to add those stages to the existing pipeline. This doesn't seem to be possible, however. But I don't see anywhere in the documentation - and don't recall seeing in the UI - that a pipeline cannot be modified after it is activated. Is this the case?

If I cannot edit an existing pipeline, should I create a new project in the DevOps Center that references the same repository and set up the pipeline from scratch and ignore the other project then?